# How do I pass a range in my UDF for calculating range size?

Tags: range, user-defined-functions

Coulds someone do me the favor of correcting the coding of my user defined function? I'm simply trying to measure the dimensions of a range specified by the user. I'm having trouble passing the range.

```
Function PageSize(MyArea As Range) As String

Dim r As Range
    Application.Volatile

    Set r = Range("MyArea") ' did not work without quotes

    Debug.Print r.Width
    Debug.Print r.Height

        PageSize = r.Width & " x " & r.Height

End Function
```

Thank you. The examples I am seeing are far more complicated than what I believe I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
Set r = Range("MyArea")
```

to

```
Set r = Range(MyArea.Address)
```

and it worked.